# Blazor lost authentication between pages

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a `Blazor WebAssembly` website that calls APIs to read/write data. The authentication is based on `Identity Server`. The user is authenticated against Identity Server and there is a Api Key (*janssen_api* in the following image) for the communication between Blazor and the APIs.

There are 3 pages in the application. So, a user can click on a page and he see the content that is coming from the APIs.

I tested the website in all my laptops and it is working. When the client started to use, he has an error. The first page calls the API and display the content correctly. When the user clicks on other pages, an error occurs.

At the beginning I thought it was a cache browser problem. But now, I can't find a solution.

The error is the following one:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: 'janssen_api' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AccessTokenNotAvailableException:
> 'janssen_api'    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request,
> HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean
> emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStreamAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Janssen.PublicationEmea.UI.Services.GapAnalysisService.GetListWithDetails(String
> username)    at
> Janssen.PublicationEmea.UI.Pages.GapAnalysis.GapAnalysis.OnInitializedAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
> taskToHandle)

[image]

Both the applications are hosted in Azure. I don't know how to fix this issue. Any ideas?

### Update

In the API project, I added the authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication(
    IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = apiSettings.Authority;
        options.ApiName = apiSettings.ApiName;
        options.ApiSecret = apiSettings.ApiSecret;
    });
```

In Blazor, in the `Program.cs` I added a `HttpClient` for each service like that

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IExportService, ExportService>(
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{apiEndpoint}"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

And this is the definition

```
public class MyAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public MyAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, 
        NavigationManager navigation, IConfiguration configuration) :
        base(provider, navigation)
    {
        string apiEndpoint = configuration["Api:EndpointsUrl"];
        string apiScope = configuration["Api:Scope"];

        ConfigureHandler(authorizedUrls: new[] { apiEndpoint },
            scopes: new[] { apiScope });
    }
}
```

### Update 2

Now, I can replicate the issue only with `Chrome` in `Incognito mode`. I still don't know how to fix it

### Update 3

The issue is in the `MyAuthorizationMessageHandler`. If I remove it from the `Program.cs` and remove `[Authorize]` attribute in the API, I don't have any error. Now, the problem is how to add the authorization.

Comment: Is there any kind of multiserver/multizone property?
(In AWS we got some problem when the machine splitted to multiple server, all session variable were lost)

Comment: No, there is one web application for the Blazor and another one for the APIs, 2 different URIs.

Comment: And how do you save that janssen_api variable?

Comment: the `janssen_api` is part of the token. I updated the code to show how I make the calls with `HttpClient`