# Blazor and Arg_NullReferenceException

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating an application with `Blazor WebAssembly` integrating with Identity Server. I have some issues with the authentication because when I call the APIs the [token expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119171/blazor-lost-authentication-between-pages) and here is the post (I'm still looking around for a solution). So, I removed the authentication and now I'm facing another issue that I can't replicate on any of my machines but only the client do :(

There is a main page with the list of entries. In this page, the user can click on a link to create a new entry. The user can insert your entry. If the user clicks on the link to see the main page, there is an error because Blazor can't find the page.

> crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Arg_NullReferenceException System.NullReferenceException:
> Arg_NullReferenceException    at
> Janssen.PublicationEmea.UI.Pages.PublicationPlan.PublicationPlan.OnInitializedAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
> taskToHandle) d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1

[image]

My `OnInitializedAsync` in the page is quite easy

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

private bool _isLock = false;
private IEnumerable<PublicationPlanUI> _data = new List<PublicationPlanUI>();
private string _errorService = "";
private string _username = "";

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;
    _username = user.Identity.Name;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_username) && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        IEnumerable<Domain.PublicationPlan> records;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && user.IsInRole("Admin"))
            records = await _service.GetListWithDetails();
        else
            records = await _service.GetListWithDetails(_username);

        if (records != null)
            _data = _mapper.Map<List<PublicationPlanUI>>(records);

        var status = await _user.GetStatus(_username);
        _isLock = status.IsPublicationClosed;
    }
}
```

all variables are initialized. I can't find what generated this error. I can see clearly that there is a `Arg_NullReferenceException` but I can't find where.

Answer (score 0):

You have a null value returned in this method:

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()

You need to check are the following objects null "authState" and "user" if they are not, process with logic, otherwise do something else.

Regards, JS

Comment: That method doesn't return any value. It only initialize variables.